# iwconfig wont associate connman does

Tags: linux, wireless-networking

Given a Cisco WDS with captive portal, open no WPA/WEP used.

I can connect with connman or other connection managers in Linux but not with regular iwconfig.

/sbin/iwconfig wlan0 essid Guest_company ap 70:F0:96:01:01:01 channel 108

Will not associate, I have done iwlist scan, tried to associate to the same network on all possible frequencies specifying the APs, this shouldn't even be needed but nope.

So this is how it looks like when connected with connman.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Guest_company"
Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.5 GHz  Access Point: 70:F0:96:01:01:01
Bit Rate=117 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm
Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
Encryption key:off
Power Management:off
Link Quality=50/70  Signal level=-60 dBm
Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:3   Missed beacon:0